# Recognizing Taproot outputs in raw transactions

Tags: script, taproot, p2tr

What can be the contents of an P2TR output script? Is it always `OP_1 0x20 <32-bit public key>`? Can multisig script be there, and if yes - in what format, and more importantly - how do I convert that script to an address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can be the contents of an P2TR output script? Is it always OP_1 0x20 <32-bit public key>?

A Taproot output contains a 32 **byte** witness program (a tweaked internal key or an untweaked public key if eschewing the tweak) after `OP_1`. The `OP_1` (01) makes it clear that it is a SegWit v1 output rather than say a SegWit v0 output (00). Any scripts are included in the leaves of the Taproot tree and hashed up to a Merkle root (which tweaks the internal public key) so the witness program can commit to various leaf scripts.

> Can multisig script be there, and if yes - in what format?

A multisig script can be in a leaf or multiple leaves of the Taproot tree. Note that a Taproot multisig script uses the opcode OP_CHECKSIGADD rather than OP_CHECKMULTISIG (outlined in [BIP 342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki)).

> How do I convert that script to an address?

The leaf scripts are hashed within the Taproot (Merkle) tree. The Merkle root then tweaks the internal public key. A breakdown of bech32m (SegWit v1) addresses is [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100508/can-you-break-down-what-data-is-encoded-into-a-bech32-address). This tweaked internal public key (or witness program) is directly included within the address.

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm - in any case, Taproot (Segwit v1) output is always 32-byte public key, which hides complexity of whatever script might be behind it. This public key is translated into address using bech32m, and that address represents the output.

Comment: Yes, a transaction output is a taproot output if and only if it consists of OP_1 followed by a 32-byte push.