# Where can I find taproot spend examples on testnet/signet?

Tags: testnet, taproot, signet, p2tr

I am in the middle of writing some Taproot libraries and would like some testnet/signet p2tr spends. Is there an easy way to find them? Most explorers don't have any filters like that. Even a list of 10 different p2tr's with various key-spends and tap-spends would be very helpful.

Comment: Not on chain, but have you seen https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/1225 ?

Comment: I swear, I had the BIP0341 specification open and this PR wasn't included. Yes, this is exactly what I need because what was there before, I couldn't really understand. Thank you.

Comment: It was also only just merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pieter said in the comments there are Taproot test vectors that have recently been [merged](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/1225) into BIP 341.

You can also find additional P2TR spends on signet, testnet on block explorers e.g. [mempool.space](https://mempool.space/signet/block/000000cb38477868d2b4881c287ec2f818631b681497cab35e09302cd9e58437). Any transaction that is spending from a `tb1p` address is a Taproot spend (`tb1q` is SegWit version 0 and `tb1p` is SegWit version 1 as discussed [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100508/can-you-break-down-what-data-is-encoded-into-a-bech32-address)).

Alternatively any [output](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/110632/recognizing-taproot-outputs-in-raw-transactions) that starts with `OP_1` (`01`) and is spent in a transaction is a Taproot spend.

There are a number of Taproot spends in recent signet/testnet blocks at the time of writing (less than a day before Taproot activates on mainnet).